# NodeJS app's CPU usage percentage goes to 100% for all requests

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I have a NodeJS app built on Express. I use pm2 to keep the app running. Sometimes, the app hangs i.e. pages just keep loading. If I try to connect to server using SSH, then that is also hanging and does not show any prompt or anything. After some time (around 1-2 minutes), app starts running normal and I can also connect to server using SSH in terminal.

To see if it is because of spike in CPU usage I connected my pm2 process with keymetrics.io . Here I noticed that on every request (even for simple login page), the CPU usage graph hits 100% and then comes back to normal.

It doesn't hang the app, but I am confused if this is normal behaviour and if not then what could be the reason for this? The app is not slow normally from user perspective.

Comment: I don't really see how anyone can know whether this is normal or not without seeing your code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I actually meant if it happens with everyone (i.e. more experienced in nodejs app monitoring etc.) that every request will make the CPU graph to hit 100% momentarily.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj you should investigate further, it is not normal for a server to become locked up for 1-2 minutes whether JavaScript is running or not. something is blocking all cores and freezes your system

Comment: @RomanMik server becoming locked up happens very rarely e.g. around once in 2 weeks. But CPU usage goes to 100% for each and every request, so that was my main question. jfriend00 has given an explanations below which makes sense as to my current scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, yes that is normal.  At the exact moment in time that any Javascript is running, the CPU is 100% occupied.  That is normal and expected.  At any given moment a CPU is either running 100% or not running at all.  There is no in-between.  When you see 50%, that is just a moving average over some time period that consists of being at 100% for half the time and at 0% for half the time.  So, the operative question is how long was the CPU at 100%.  If it was a few ms, that's nothing.  If it was a few minutes, that's likely an issue.

Most monitoring tools will show you more of a moving average over time so you don't see instantaneous bursts to 100%, but if your monitoring tool is showing you an instantaneous burst at 100%, then that is perfectly normal.  That's the moment that actual Javascript is running.

If you saw your CPU at 100% for a meaningful amount of time (like for minutes), then that would probably indicate an issue to look into because during that time your server is probably not responsive to other requests.  But, a momentary and short spike to 100% is normal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I wanted to know. A colleague told me that there app never reached higher than 50% CPU usage. So I think they would be using a different monitoring tool as you mentioned which shows average over time. Could it also be because there server was multi-core while mine is a single-core?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj - node.js runs all your Javascript in a single core so it doesn't usually make a big difference to have multiple cores.  But, it again depends upon the monitoring tool and how it shows things.  If you have a 4-core CPU and one CPU is 100% occupied, a monitoring tool might show you 25% overall usage because you have three other cores doing nothing.  The main issue with node.js is that you don't want to write node.js code that hogs the CPU for long periods of time because that will likely make a less responsive server.  But short bursts of 100% is normal.

Comment: Thanks again :) I was really confused and your explanations helped a lot.